# Is there an efficient way to perform this ActiveRecord query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several models: `Tickets`, `Seats`, `Sections`, `TicketTypes`.

`Ticket belongs_to Seat`

`Seat belongs_to Section`

`Section belongs_to a TicketType`

and `TicketType` holds all the price information.

At the moment, to get some of the price information I need to do `ticket.seat.section.ticket_type.things_i_need` which selects seat, then executes another select statement for the section, then another for the ticket type.

Is there a more efficient way to get the information I need? I tried using `joins`, `merge`, and `includes` but couldn't get the information I need.

Comment: Easy. Just make ticket belong to a ticket type. It's an obvious relation, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've tried this but I would think it would be:

```
@ticket = Ticket.includes(seat: { section: [:ticket_type] }).find(params[:id])
@ticket.seat.section.ticket_type.things_i_need
```